# Get access of an element from json Php

Tags: php, json

I have a Json as follows in which I 've to get only  transId inside response in php. please help as I am new to php

```
{
    "type": null,
    "requestuid": null,
    "orderId": "anand12345",
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "statusCode": "SUCCESS",
    "statusMessage": "SUCCESS",
    "response": {
        "transId": "1408544"
    },
    "metadata": "Testing Data"
}
```

Comment: you want to extract `transId`. is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, I exactly want to get transId

Comment: You might need to look at this function http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php . Not that a boolean can be passed as second argument to force the conversion to produce an associative array or a StdClass

Comment: _Suggestion:_ Before posting, make sure you have done proper research. It would have been pretty easy to find this information since it's been asked and answered many many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$json = '{
 "type": null,
 "requestuid": null,
 "orderId": "anand12345",
 "status": "SUCCESS",
 "statusCode": "SUCCESS",
 "statusMessage": "SUCCESS",
 "response": {"transId": "1408544"},
 "metadata": "Testing Data"
}';

$arr = json_decode($json,true);
$transId = $arr['response']['transId'];
```

Answer (score 1):

read your file and store its content as a string (here i directly declared a string stored in `$json` )
using [json_decode php function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) you get an object with all your data and just have to use field names to access your data

```
$json = '{
"type": null,
"requestuid": null,
"orderId": "anand12345",
"status": "SUCCESS",
"statusCode": "SUCCESS",
"statusMessage": "SUCCESS",
"response": {
    "transId": "1408544"
},
"metadata": "Testing Data"

}';


$decoded = json_decode($json);
echo $decoded->response->transId;
```